# String as pointer vs array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, constants

I was wondering what the differences are between the following definitions:

```
// file.cpp:
namespace n
{
static char const * const str1 = "hello";
static char const str2[] = "hello";
}
```

Behaviors I want, and I think they both provide:

- They both refer to immutable data (because the data is char consts)
- Neither variable can be modified (because str1 is defined as a * const and because str2 is an array, which can't be used as an l-value?)
- They both have internal linkage (via static)
- They both have namespace scope
- If a pointer to either string data is made available to a different module (via some function not specified here), the memory for those strings will be valid (str1 because it points to a string literal, and str2 because the array is declared at namespace scope)

Is there any differences that are guaranteed by the language?
If there are behaviors that are implementation dependent, how can I investigate the difference on my different platforms?

(For this example, I am not interested in contrasting these behaviors with std::string options, although feel free to talk about that too if you think other readers would be interested.)

Comment: there is no difference.

Comment: @TaylorFlores No difference? Really?

Comment: @TaylorFlores yes there is!

Comment: oh? sorry, maybe I should be asking this question

Comment: @TaylorFlores Just read my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily run into the differences between the two stemming from the fact that one is an array and another is a pointer. For example `sizeof` will evaluate to different (i.e. unrelated) values for `n::str1` and `n::str2`. Also, both of them are lvalues (what made you think they are not?), which means that you can apply `&` to them and get completely different results

```
&n::str1; // evaluates to a `char const *const *` value
&n::str2; // evaluates to a `char const (*)[6]` value
```

Also note that the first one is a direct pointer into some immutable implementation-owned "string literal storage area", while the second one is an array owned by "you", which is initialized by copying data from the aforementioned "string literal storage area". The implementation is allowed to merge those implementation-owned string literals across the entire program. For example, of you declare another pointer initialized with the same string literal

```
char const *str_another = "hello";
```

the language guarantees that `str_another` does not point at `n::str2`

```
assert(str_another != n::str2); // will not fail
```

Yet it does not guarantee that `str_another` is different from `n::str1`

```
assert(str_another != n::str1); // can fail
```

Comment: The l-value came up in VC++2012 'n::str2 = n::str2;' yielded "error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value".  The primary thing I was trying to emphasize is that neither str1 or str2 was assignable.  The reason why is also interesting, but perhaps secondary.

Comment: @user2246255: `n::str2 = n::str2` is a bad example, since it can fail simply because of array type decay. But anyway, assignment requires a *modifiable* lvalue on the LHS. If something is non-assignable it does not mean that it is not lvalue. It might mean that the lvalue is simply non-modifiable. The `n::str2` is a non-modifiable lvalue.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are: one is still an array, the other one is a pointer. And pointers and arrays are not the same.

One specific aspect may be the use of the `sizeof` operator - for the pointer, it won't result in the length of the string, on the array it will (the terminating NUL character counted in as well, of course).

Answer (score 1):

`&n::str1` is a `char const * const *`, but `&n::str2` is a `char const (*)[6]`.

You can get some differences with function overload resolution, but probably only if one of the overloads uses a reference-to-array type.

```
template<typename T>
void f(T); // #1

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void f(T (&)[N]); // #2

void g() {
    f(n::str1); // calls #1, T is char const*
    f(n::str2); // calls #2, T is char const, N is 6.
}
```

Also, as @H2CO3 points out, `sizeof(n::str1)` is `sizeof(char const*)`, but `sizeof(n::str2)` is 6.